# invalid device ordinal on cudaMemPrefetchAsync

Tags: cuda

I'm running a toy CUDA sample on my GeForce 1080 Ti (Pascal) on windows 10 and CUDA 9.2.

Goal is to test [cudaMemPrefetchAsync](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8dc9199943d421bc8bc7f473df12e42) to the CPU, as it's supposed to work.

However, I get a CUDA error (invalid device ordinal) on this particular line.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void fill(int* a, int val, int N) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
        a[k] = val;
    }
}

__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int N)
{
    for (int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
        a[i] += b[i];
    }
}

inline void check(cudaError_t err, const char* file, int line) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        ::fprintf(stderr, "ERROR at %s[%d] : %s\n", file, line, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        abort();
    }
}

#define CUDA_CHECK(err) do { check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); } while(0)

int main()
{
    int deviceId;
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaGetDevice(&deviceId));
    const int N = 1024*1024*32;
    int *a, *b;
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMallocManaged(&a, N * sizeof(int)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMallocManaged(&b, N * sizeof(int)));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(a, N * sizeof(int), cudaCpuDeviceId)); // program breaks here
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(b, N * sizeof(int), cudaCpuDeviceId));
    fill(a, 1, N);
    fill(a, 2, N);

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(a, N * sizeof(int), deviceId));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(b, N * sizeof(int), deviceId));

    add<<<32, 256>>>(a, b, N);

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaGetLastError());
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    return 0;
}
```

Is that a hardware/driver/OS limitation? Can I simply ignore the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that a hardware/driver/OS limitation?

Yes, the latter. Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements)

> GPUs with SM architecture 6.x or higher (Pascal class or newer)
>   provide additional Unified Memory features such as on-demand page
>   migration and GPU memory oversubscription that are outlined throughout
>   this document. Note that currently these features are *only* supported
>   on Linux operating systems.

So asynchronous page migration is not supported in Windows at the moment and that it why you get an error when you try to enable it.